# Spreadsheet barcode input

Tags: google-sheets

When I use my barcode scanner and scan a barcode, the code is sent to my spreadsheets. However, I need to press space to enter the next cell. Is there an auto-enter function so I can go to the next cell by just scanning a new barcode? Thanks

I tried to scan a new barcode once one had already been scanned, however, it goes in the same cell as the previous one I scanned.

EX:
QR CODE
(Assume "[ ]" is a cell reference)

[712783602911621935869001]

[712783602911621935869001]

[712783602911621935869001]

[712783602911621935869001]

but I try sometime later, this happens, where all the numbers go into one cell reference:

[712783602911621935869001712783602911621935869001712783602911621935869001712783602911621935869001]

would somebody know? Thanks for the help.

Comment: many barcode scanners you can reprogram to insert that

Comment: Most handheld USB barcode scanners function as a USB keyboard, pressing ENTER after scanning a code. Could you tell us how your scanner functions? Open Notepad, and scan a couple of barcodes. What do you see?

Comment: Additionally, are you trying to go one cell to the right or one cell down after scanning each barcode?

Comment: I am with @FelixAn with this one about how Barcode Scanner works. However alternative routes to consider are using Apps Script. What I am thinking is that right after you scan the codes you can add additional button to your Google Sheet to split the barcodes to desired character counts if you have uniform lengths, or adding additional character to your barcodes and have it run to some formula. But I totally suggest  using Apps Script so you can delete the container cells contents and create new set at the same.

Comment: I found something that is similar to your case despite of not having accepted answer, the comments and the suggestions might be helpful to you as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836981/automatically-advancing-cells-after-scanning-data

Comment: I am trying to go one cell to the bottom
Regarding the note pad, the number just goes right behind the previous one, rather than going to the next line.

Comment: @Jackson Most scanners have some "configuration" codes you can scan (usually provided with the manual) which enables or disables automatically pressing the ENTER key after scanning a barcode. In your case, the function was probably disabled. What brand and model of scanner are you using?

Comment: @FelixAn I am using a NETUM Scanner USB 1D.

Comment: @Jackson Here are the configuration codes: https://www.netum.net/pages/barcode-scanner-user-manuals